# Como funciona Symbol no ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Na nova especificação do Javascript [ECMAScript (ES6)](http://es6-features.org/) foi criado um novo tipo primitivo chamado `Symbol()` qual é a utilidade dele?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Symbol()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) é um novo primitivo. Como `Function`, `Object` e `Number`.

O que é especial é que ele gera algo de único. Um `Symbol` é sempre único. Há quem diga que gera *tokens* (por serem únicos), sempre diferentes.

Ou seja:

```
var a = Symbol(123);
var b = Symbol(123);
console.log(a == b, a === b); // false, false
```

es6fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ihpaffj0/

Isto é verdade curiosamente até em nomes de propriedades de objetos.

```
var obj = {};
var a = obj[Symbol('prop')] = 'foo';
var b = obj[Symbol('prop')] = 'bar';
console.log(a, b, obj[Symbol('prop')]); // 'foo', 'bar', <vazio>
```

es6fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ihpapvuv/

**Onde poderá ser útil?**

É dificil adivinhar todos os casos de uso, mas alguns que imagino:

- gerar Symbols unicos para ids e/ou sessões
- evitar choques de nomes de propriedades de objetos

#### Boa leitura <sup>em Inglês</sup>

- Blog Axel Rauschmayer: http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html
- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: +1, legal, mas em quais cenários ele vai ser útil?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues juntei ideias, se surgirem mais vou juntar.

Comment: Acho que a ideia principal é que sejam usados como nomes de propriedades (Chaves). As chaves dos objetos nativos só são strings por motivo de compatibilidade com ES5-

Comment: Bruh, isso sim é uma resposta +1

Comment: Essa questão de só poder acessar a uma propriedade se tiver a chave correspondente me parece estranha. Afinal, as propriedades cujas chaves são `Symbol`s ainda são enumeráveis, não? Usando esse seu último código como exemplo, não seria o caso de fazer `var mensagemSecreta = obj[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)[0]];` e assim ter acesso ao valor mesmo sem conhecer a chave?

Comment: @mgibsonbr tens razão. E usando `Symbol.for('str');` ainda é mais fácil com `Symbol.keyFor(instancia)` ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3ou4hzd/)). Bom ver-te! Se andasses por aqui mais vezes as respostas estariam ainda mais em ordem :)